# What are substitutes of caffeine?

Tags: caffeine

Are there any substitutes of caffeine?

In terms of similar effects such as energy, alertness, decreased fatigue, increased metabolic rate, etc.?

Comment: I think this might be off-topic for this site; see [help/on-topic] and [help] for more on what's on-topic here. You might also consider asking at [biology.se] for other topics like physiological effects of stimulants.

Comment: I voted to close but I agree that the question could instead be moved to another SE site.

Comment: Caffeine is a xanthine derivative, so other members of that family could be considered "substitutes".  Aminophylline and theophylline are probably the two that get used most often in US medicine.

Answer (score 4):

While you may not find many perfect substitutes for caffeine which will give you all of the same effects, there are things you can do which will decrease your need for caffeine.  A quick search reveals a few things you can do:

- Eat Apples and other fruits - Calories, high fructose levels, vitamins,
  and antioxidants they provide are all important for sustaining energy levels
  throughout the day.
- Maintain your [Vitamin B12](http://familydoctor.org/familydoctor/en/prevention-wellness/food-nutrition/nutrients/vitamin-b-12.printerview.all.html) level - Decreased levels of Vitamin
  B-12 - found in fish, shellfish, meat, and dairy products - can cause
  fatigue and weakness.  It plays a key role in mental clarity and
  energy enhancement which is why its included in many energy drinks.
- Exercise - Many studies have shown that exercising in the morning can
  give you more of an energy boost than caffeine.
- Get a good nights sleep - well, obviously.

I guess you could sum this answer up with saying a balanced diet, exercise, and a healthy sleep cycle all are necessary for you to sustain your energy levels throughout the day, remain alert, and increase your metabolism.

When life happens and you can't get a good nights sleep, healthy breakfast, exercise, etc... stick with Caffeine.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're a little confused here.

Coffee contains caffeine (a psychoactive drug), as does tea (although in lower quantities). Coca-cola and related beverages also contain caffeine.

If you want similar effects to those you've listed, but without caffeine, your options are going to be limited to, well, other psychoactive drugs. All drugs have effects and side-effects that are rather different, so there is nothing that's the same as caffeine.

However, if you're feeling tired in the morning but can't/don't want to drink coffee, a big glass of cold water is a great way to wake up (and arguably better than coffee, dare I say it!).